# Not able to do automatic conversion of scripts from sql server 2008 to 2005

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, sql-server-2005

I have stored procedures created in `sql server 2008 R2`. Now, one of our clients is using `Sql Server 2005`, and scripts need to be converted to old version as there is syntax incompatibility like `date` is not supported in `sql server 2005`. Since the number of stored procedures is large, 364 in my case, doing it manually will take me days as I need to check for every supported/unsupported syntax.

**What I tried :**

I tried to generate scripts by setting option of `Scripts for Sql version` as `2005`, but still scripts generated doesn't contain correct syntax as in case of replacing `date` with `datetime`.

Is there any other way, should `Sql server` not do it automatically!!

Comment: Nope. This will be a thinking persons task. Sorry to say it, but you're in for some effort.

Comment: "Please note that SQL Server 2005 will be out of extended support on Apr 12, 2016. If you are still running SQL Server 2005 after April 12, 2016, you will no longer receive security updates.." - tell your client!!!    http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlreleaseservices/archive/2011/01/27/end-of-mainstream-support-for-sql-server-2005-and-end-of-service-pack-support-for-sql-server-2008-sp1.aspx

Comment: Problem is my employer wants me to update them backwards, although in future there can be many more scripts having same problem, I had already suggested updating Sql server but to no avail

Comment: Then you're SOOL! So wants your employer going to do when that SQL Server 2005 box gets compromised?

Comment: Sool!! What is that?

Comment: Apparently his vision seems to be satisfying client needs at any costs, even if it takes breaking necks of developers like me!!

Comment: @ubaid gadha you need to do it maually :)

Comment: If you posted one of the procs we could probably suggest half a dozen reasons why this is a bad idea, but I suspect your employer is not much of a 'listener'. You need to remember this is not just a development task but an ongoing support task.

Comment: Yes, It should be support task, but hardly any such hierarchy is followed here. One of my reasons I am putting forward my resignation

Comment: Is 364 the number of all stored procedures, or just those that won't run on sql server 2005?

Comment: It is the number of stored procedure which need to be converted to old version, each script may contain syntax which is not backward compatible with sql server 2005

Comment: Then I suggest that you first try to run each of them on sql server 2005. you will probably find that at least some of them are running fine. after that, you are probably going to have to fix those that don't manually, one by one.

Comment: SOOL = sh!t out of luck